# How to take just most popular post and display it in another section?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a website that lets users post without having to register or log in, I display most popualar posts on my page but users can choose to display new posts, most liked or disliked, random etc... Now I want to take #1 post (the one with the most likes-dislikes) from my most popular posts page. I will try to explain as much as I could.

This is my posts feed, so users can choose between popular, best and new, and you can see the posts are displaying in a vertical way. And there is my side box where I want to put just that one most popular post from my popular posts feed.

My posts and where I want to put most popular post

[image]

**Here is a code how I display posts:**

```
       <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    // Get Total Comments
    $comssql = "SELECT 'X' FROM comments WHERE confessId = ".$row['confessId']." AND isActive = 1";
    $commentstotal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $comssql) or die('-4'.mysqli_error());
    $totComments = mysqli_num_rows($commentstotal);
    if ($totComments == '1') { $comText = 'Comment'; } else { $comText = 'Comments'; }
    if ($row['totalViews'] == '1') { $viewText = 'View'; } else { $viewText = 'Views'; }
    $shareURL = $set['installUrl'].'page.php?page=view&confession='.$row['confessId'];
                            ?>
    <div class="confession">
    <div class="left"><span class="label label-confess1"><?php echo $row['totalViews'].' '.$viewText; ?></span></div>
    <div class="right"><span class="label label-confess2"><?php echo timeago($row['postDate']); ?></span></div>
    <div class="confessionstyle"><p>
    <font color="#fff3b2">
    <?php
    if ($filterProfanity == '0') {
    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(filterwords($row['confessText'])));
                                                } else {
                                                    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['confessText']));
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </font>
    </p></div>

    <input type="hidden" id="confessId" name="confessId_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" />
 <div class="confession-actions">

  <div class="likes">
  <span class="label label-confess first liked">

     <a href="" id="likeIt<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="likeIt_<?php echo $count; ?> text-success">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span id="likesVal_<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalLikes']; ?></span>
       </a>
            </span>
             </div>
      <div class="dislikes">
  <span class="label label-confess disliked">
   <a href="" id="dislikeIt<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="dislike_<?php echo $count; ?> text-danger">
    <span id="dislikesVal_<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalDislikes']; ?></span> <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
        </a>
     </span>
    </div>



          <?php if ($row['hasImage'] != '0') { ?>
         <span class="label label-confess"><i class="fa fa-picture-o img"></i></span>
                <?php } ?>

            <div class="comments">

    <div class="divide"><a href="page.php?page=view&confession=<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <?php echo $totComments.' '.$comText; ?>
               </a></div>
       </div>

 <div class="divide2"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo $set['siteName']; ?>%20Confession:%20<?php echo ellipsis($row['confessText'],65); ?>%20&url=<?php echo $shareURL; ?>" class="btn btn-tw btn-sm" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $twitterShareTooltip; ?>">
<i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color:white"></i>
  </a></div></div>

 <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<?php
$count++;
      }
?>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-loadmore btn-block" id="loadMore"><?php echo $loadMoreText; ?></a><br />
</div>
        <?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($adres) > 0) {
while ($ad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($adres)) {
                        ?>
<div class="adText">
<h3><a href="<?php echo clean($ad['adUrl']); ?>"><?php echo clean($ad['adTitle']); ?> <i class="fa fa-external-link pull-right"></i></a></h3>
<p><a href="<?php echo clean($ad['adUrl']); ?>"><?php echo nl2br(clean($ad['adText'])); ?></a></p>
<span class="label label-default"><?php echo $advertisementText; ?></span>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>

</div>
```

**Here's a php for displaying most popular posts:**

```
    else if ($view == $viewNavLinkPopular) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                confessions.confessId,
                (IFNULL(confessions.firstName, '')) AS firstName,
            confessions.confessText,
            DATE_FORMAT(confessions.postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
            hasImage,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(confessions.postDate) AS orderDate,
            confessions.isActive,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
            FROM
            confessions
            WHERE isActive = 1
            ORDER BY totalViews DESC, orderDate DESC";
            $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-3' . mysqli_error());
                }
```

If you need any other code in order to help me just ask.
I tried with putting the same code I use for displaying them but with changing the count to 1, but that didn't helped. So to make it clear, I want to take most popular post from popular section and display it in a Most Liked Confession section (See in the image I attached). Hoping for some help, thanks in advice guys!

Comment: Please re-paste your code with only 4 indentations on the left most part and 2 spaces instead of tabs. Your code is unreadable and you really should read [mcve] - If you want to move the post using JavaScript then post  ONLY HTML, CSS and JavaScript instead of PHP we have to render using our eyeballs

Comment: I did, sorry Im new to Stack. Do you maybe know the answer of my question?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you one suggestion. In the query where you're getting the results for the filter most-liked or disliked. Try giving the query 'LIMIT 1' at the end. If that's not working. Try to get all the outputs and them print only the first part of your output.
Hope this would help